# How to parse hex codes from JSON data in R

Tags: r, json, hex, rvest

I have JSON scraped from the web in a format such as this:

```
\x22datetime\x22\x3A\x222019\x2D05\x2D12\x2017\x3A00\x3A00\x22\x7D\x5D
```

If I copy and paste the data in, it parses quite well:

```
\"datetime\":\"2019-05-12 17:00:00\"}]
```

However when I import the data as a text file, or when it is scraped from the web using `rvest`, each backslash is displayed as a double backslash:

```
\\x22datetime\\x22\\x3A\\x222019\\x2D05\\x2D12\\x2017\\x3A00\\x3A00\\x22\\x7D\\x5D
```

I would like to know how to get R to parse the hex codes as special characters i.e. so it looks like this:

```
"datetime":"2019-05-12 17:00:00"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the data already in the text files, here's one way to reverse the problem. In general, though, R uses backslashes a bit different than many other languages: only a few things allow a single backslash (e.g., `\x##`, `\u####`, `\n`, `\b`, `\r`, `\t`, perhaps others). A literal backslash is a double-backslash. Since your text files have a literal backslash, followed by "x" and some numbers, R dutifully reads them in as literal strings, not as the hex-code that `\x##` is meant to represent.

```
s <- '\\x22datetime\\x22\\x3A\\x222019\\x2D05\\x2D12\\x2017\\x3A00\\x3A00\\x22\\x7D\\x5D'
```

This part matches any instance of `\x`, but since it's R we need `\\\\` to represent a literal `\` ... odd, I know. We also capture the two following hex-digits:

```
gre <- gregexpr("\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}", s)
regm <- regmatches(s, gre)[[1]]
regm
#  [1] "\\x22" "\\x22" "\\x3A" "\\x22" "\\x2D" "\\x2D" "\\x20" "\\x3A" "\\x3A" "\\x22" "\\x7D"
# [12] "\\x5D"
```

With this `regm`, we can use a hex-conversion and some `raw` functions to convert to the real ascii characters:

```
sapply(as.raw(strtoi(substr(regm, 3, 4), 16L)), rawToChar)
#  [1] "\"" "\"" ":"  "\"" "-"  "-"  " "  ":"  ":"  "\"" "}"  "]"
```

The function `regmatches` not only *extracts* the specific patterns within the string, it can also *replace* them.

```
regmatches(s, gre) <- list(sapply(as.raw(strtoi(substr(regm, 3, 4), 16L)), rawToChar))
s
# [1] "\"datetime\":\"2019-05-12 17:00:00\"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is with the scraping, as it looks that what you are importing is literally strings like "\x22", instead of an encoded ":".

But to emulate "what would I get if I typed this input at a prompt", you can use `eval` and `parse`, like this:

```
input <- readLines(file) # Or similar
# Next line for testing, note both single and double quotes
input <- '"\\x22datetime\\x22\\x3A\\x222019\\x2D05\\x2D12\\x2017\\x3A00\\x3A00\\x22\\x7D\\x5D"'
result <- eval(parse(text=input))
```